# How to Manually limit the number of DBMS_SCHEDULERS in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, queue

Is it possible to manually reduce the maximum number of DBMS_SCHEDULERS that ran on Oracle SQL Server ?   i am using SQL Developer as GUI tool.

Comment: Have a look at the max_job_slave_processes parameter. Maybe that's what you need. 

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin001.htm#i1006314

Comment: There is no such thing as "Oracle SQL Server" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DBMS_SCHEDULER setting max_job_slave processes](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1109295?tstart=0)

from article above:
to limit number of job processes:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute (
    attribute => 'max_job_slave_processes',
    value     => 2);
END;
/
```

but draw attention on parameter `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES`
if the parameter is not 0, then it's value will take precedence over the
`MAX_JOB_SLAVE_PROCESSES` attribute